# css id wildcard selector with children

Tags: css, selector, wildcard

i dont know exactly how to explain this but i have the following situation. I have many divs whose IDs start with "row", such as row1, row2, etc. All of them contain another div which has a class called "element". What i want to do is to create a rule for all those "element" divs so i wrote something like this:

```
[id*="row"] .element {width:0;}
```

My html is like this:

```
<div id="row1">
 <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div id="row2">
 <div class="element"></div>
</div>
<div id="row3">
 <div class="element"></div>
</div>

and so on...
```

It didn't work. Could you please tell me what's wrong? By the way, i cant just add a rule for "element" only because other divs with different IDs have "element" inside too and are supposed to have different styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well actually your code works fine.

Look at this:

```
<div id="row3">
 <div class="element">three</div>
</div>
<div id="notARow">
 <div class="element">three</div>
</div>
```

With

```
[id*="row"] .element {color: red}
```

.. and notice that the id's with row is red.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Puw5C/)**

For more info about attribute selecors - check out [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors)

---

If I were to guess why this didn't work for you, I would say that the problem is related to specificity.

To check this, right-click 'inspect element' on one of the .element classes and see if your attribute selector rule is crossed out / overridden by a more specific rule.

Comment: You are right, there is some shit overriding it. Its div.element-title {width:50%;] unfortunately i cant take it off.

Answer (score 0):

You can just select them using `.element`.  Also, should use class on those `row` divs, then you don't need to select by ID.

Like so:

```
<div id="1" class="row">
    <div class="element"></div?
</div>
```

and so on to be selected as:

```
.row .element {
}
```

You would only need to include something in addition to `.element` if there are conflicting elements with that class on the page you DON'T want to select.

If those are the only ones, use this instead:

```
.elements {
}
```

Comment: That wont work because i said i have other divs with "element" divs inside but different IDs.

Comment: That's why I gave you the second option

Comment: It would be the same since the rule applies for all "element" divs other than the ones with the ID "row-%".